# В строке найти первое вхождение знака (от 1 до 9), все что до него удалить

Tags: php, строки

Здравствуйте.
Есть строки

```
$string1 = '00000103';
$string2 = '00000344';
$string3 = '00023560';
```

Требуется получить 103, 344, 23564.
Пытался делать так

```
$result = mb_stristr($string,'/[1-9]/',false);
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Александр, если ответы вас устраивают, выберите подходящий вам

Answer (score 4):

1) Если вы хотите использовать регулярные выражения, то вам нужна функция [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace.php) для замены нулей на пустоту. Вот пример:

```
$str = "0000103";
$result = preg_replace('/^[0]+/', '', $str);
var_dump($result);
```

Ей так же можно указать массив строк, тогда она вернет то же массив.

2) Вот вариант на выборку всех чисел, которые начинаются на `>0` с помощью функции [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match.php):

```
$str = "0000103";
preg_match('/[1-9][0-9]+/', $str, $match);
var_dump($match);
```

3) И чем вам не нравится вариант приведения числа к инту?

```
$str = "0000103";
var_dump((int) $str);
```

4) Еще как вариант от @Etki в комментарии – действительно можно просто удалить слева символы `0` в строке слева:

```
$str = "0000103";
var_dump(ltrim($str, '0'));
```

Последний вариант так же удалит пробелы у другие символы см. доку по [ltrim()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.ltrim.php).

Comment: Есть строка, нужно число. (int), конечно. intval ещё base проверяет.

Answer (score 1):

Regexp снова не нужны:

```
echo (strval(intval ('00000344', 10))); // 344
```

Только я не понял почему из '00023560' получаете 23564? :-)

PS. Если нужно число из строки - достаточно intval().

Comment: если считать, что там всегда zerofill (о чем автор не сказал), то тогда ltrim уж

Comment: @Etki Ух ты, и такое есть!

Comment: @Etki я тут подумал, а ltrim с отрицательными "числами" типа "-00013" работать же не будет?

Comment: Еще раз: если там зерофилл (**о чем автор не сказал**), то можно лтрим, если нет, то нельзя. По условиям там вообще не нули слева.

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = '00000103';
preg_match('/[1-9][0-9]+/', $str, $match);
echo $match[0];
```

Comment: `$str = '00010001001';` - выведет просто единицу

Comment: А как же нули в середине или конце строки?

Comment: да, не обратил внимания, тогда нужно добавить [0-9]